# Replace nested placeholder in string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string with a placeholder and I want to replace placeholder with value. But the issue is placeholder itself contain multiple placeholders.

Eg.

```
string s = "My name is {Name}";
```

Now, I want to replace {Name} but {Name} contains following placeholders

1. {First Name} {Last Name}
2. {First Name}
3. {Last Name}

I want to pick one 1 placeholder randomly and replace with {Name}.

In last I want the following output

`My name is ABC` Or

`My name is ABC XYZ` Or

`My name is XYZ`

Comment: Use regex, but don't make it your [second problem](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Comment: @Girish see if my answer solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use some methods for solve this problem

Regexp

```
string s = "My name is {Name}";
string result= Regex.Replace(s, "{name}", "ABC");
```

Format

```
string name="ABC";
string result= string.Format("My name is {0}", name);
```

Interpolation expression

```
string name="ABC";
string result= $"My name is {name}";
```

Comment: In interpolation example exchange `Name` with `name`.

Comment: @csa I want random placeholder in {Name}. So it may be {First Name}, {Last Name} or {First Name} {Last Name} not only {First Name}

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


static void Main()
{
    string s = "My name is {Name} - {Gender}";

    Dictionary<string, List<string>> placeHolders = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
    {
        {"Name", new List<string>{"FIRST", "LAST"}},
        {"Gender", new List<string>{"Male", "Female"}}
    };
    foreach(var item in placeHolders)
    {
        if (item.Value.Count == 2) item.Value.Add(string.Join(" ", item.Value));
    }
    var sSplit = Regex.Split(s, "(\\{[a-zA-Z]*\\})");
    List<string> results = new List<string> { "" };
    foreach (var item in sSplit)
    {
        Match m = Regex.Match(item, "{([a-zA-Z]*)}");
        if (!m.Success)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++) results[i] += item;
        }
        else
        {
            if (placeHolders.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value))
            {
                List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
                foreach (var r in results)
                {
                    foreach (var p in placeHolders[m.Groups[1].Value]) tempList.Add(r + p);
                }
                results = tempList;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var str in results)
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
My name is FIRST - Male
My name is FIRST - Female
My name is FIRST - Male Female
My name is LAST - Male
My name is LAST - Female
My name is LAST - Male Female
My name is FIRST LAST - Male
My name is FIRST LAST - Female
My name is FIRST LAST - Male Female
```